# Open several mat-dialogs one by one after the previous one is closed

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-material, mat-dialog

In my code I have a button which will browse a list of data and open a `mat-dialog` for each data.

Unfortunately, during the course of the loop, all the `mat-dialogs` open.

What I would like to happen is that by using the `dialogRef.afterClosed()` method, depending on the result (`true`) the next `mat-dialog` opens or (`false`) the loop ends.

```
openDialog(): void {
  this.data.forEach(data => {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, {
      disableClose: true
    });
    dialogRef.componentInstance.data = data;

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      if (result) {
        // open next mat-dialog
      } else {
        // stop loop
      }
    });
  });
}

<div mat-dialog-actions>
  <button mat-button (click)="_dialogRef.close(true)">Ok</button>
  <button mat-button (click)="_dialogRef.close(false)">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

[**StackBlitz Here**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/open-mat-dialogs-one-by-one-after-the-previous-one-is-closed?file=src/app/dialog-overview-example.ts)

How can I do this? I don't know how to go about it.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by rxjs takeWhile

```
from(this.data)
      .pipe(
        concatMap(x => {
          const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, {
            disableClose: true
          });

          dialogRef.componentInstance.data = x;

          return dialogRef.afterClosed();
        }),
        takeWhile(Boolean)
      ).subscribe();
```

See https://stackblitz.com/edit/open-mat-dialogs-one-by-one-after-the-previous-one-is-cl-yqprmt?file=src/app/dialog-overview-example.ts

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution, in my original code I am using a list of list ([new StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/open-mat-dialogs-one-by-one-after-the-previous-one-is-closed-2?file=src/app/dialog-overview-example.ts)) and I can't seem to set up your solution with a list of list can you help me?

Comment: Just flat the array https://stackblitz.com/edit/open-mat-dialogs-one-by-one-after-the-previous-one-is-cl-k3geac?file=src/app/dialog-overview-example.ts

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by marking you method as `async` and awaiting your dialog `afterClosed()` call, but since `await`works only with promises you need to convert the `Observable` to a  `Promise`.

Here is a the solution that works for me

```
@Component({
  selector: "dialog-overview-example",
  templateUrl: "dialog-overview-example.html",
  styleUrls: ["dialog-overview-example.css"]
})
export class DialogOverviewExample {
  data: any[] = DATA;
  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {}

  async openDialog() {

  for(var i =0; i < this.data.length; i++) {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, {
        disableClose: true
      });
      dialogRef.componentInstance.data = this.data[i];
      var result = await  dialogRef.afterClosed().toPromise();
        if (!result) {
          console.log("Stop loop", result);
          break;
        }
        // else continue the loop

   }
 }
}
```

**[Stackblitz Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/open-mat-dialogs-one-by-one-after-the-previous-one-is-cl-uow3ue?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdialog-overview-example.ts)**

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to not use an iterator (foreach) (in fact, I would discourage using one), but instead trigger `openDialog` again in the subscribe if there is still more data to display (queue-like approach). Of course this requires to remove the shown data from the list, but it would also allow for new data being appended to it in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on the "queued dialogs service" on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-dialog-queue?file=src%2Fapp%2Fservices%2Fdialog.ts).
Calling the service's `open` method

- will show the dialog, if the queue is empty or the dialog has a higher `priority` than the currently displayed one
- will queue the dialog, if there is a dialog with higher `priority` already opened

There may be dragons along the way.